# Modify line height in PDF

Tags: pdf, message-templates, ckeditor

I need to adjust the line height on PDF when creating letters. I tried to modify

```
.cke_editable
{
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.6em; <- I tried 1em
}
```

...in

```
/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/ckeditor/contents.css
```

My modification is visible in CKEditor but doesn't change anything on the generated PDF.

What is the best approach to do this ? I'm using Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.5.8 and CKEditor 4.

Thanks

**EDIT**

From @Flying comment, I noticed that CKEditor creates

```
<span style="line-height:1.6em">...</span>
```

...around all newly created paragraph (so each time I hit backspace). I can get rid of these span's by using "Remove Format" ("Tx" button).

So I guess my question becomes "Why does CKE add span's around p's with inline css style ?"

I found some useful resources, still need to check :

http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/ckeditor-4.01-inserting-span-elements-everywhere-with-a-line-height-of-1.6em

https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998

Comment: Have you tried to put the line-height tag inside the html-code of the PDF template? (PDF templates are using inline CSS, so you probably should use it on a div or something)

Comment: @Flying Thanks for the lead, I edited my answer

Comment: TinyMCE does not include those spans...